# Clean And Cross-Browser Friendly Way Of Loading A Large Background Video

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to load a large HTML5 background video.  Using the tags specified below, the result is unattractive & sloppy.  The background video loads half way and appears small at first before following the css rule and resizes.

CSS:

```
video{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    min-width:100% !important;
    min-height:100% !important;
    z-index:-100;
    background:url('img/poster.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    -webkit-transition:1s opacity;
    transition:1s opacity
    }
```

HTML:

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="" poster="img/poster.jpg" id="videoshow">
    <source src="videos/video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Using a third party plugin to Jquery, such as BigVideo.js is bloated & buggy.

What I'm trying to do now is hide the video and only make it visible once it is loaded with Jquery like this, but it doesn't work.  Can anyone please tell me if I'm going in the right direction, or if there is a more direct way of doing this? -

```
$("#videoshow").addEventListener('load', function() {
    var video = document.querySelector('#videoshow');

function checkLoad() {
    if (video.readyState === 4) {
        $("#videoshow").css('display','block');
    }
}

checkLoad();
}, false);
```

As mentioned below, I have implemented the following oncanplay script -

```
var vid = document.getElementById("videoshow");
vid.oncanplay = function() {
    vid.style.display = 'block';
};
```

But it's hit and miss... Sometimes the video stays tiny centered on the screen, and other times it renders 100% how the css specifies.  I'm using the latest version of safari & similar sites like AirBnB, Paypal, etc...  don't ever have this issue.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: i think bigvideo.js is pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utilizing the `canplay` event:

> Sent when enough data is available that the media can be played, at
>   least for a couple of frames.  This corresponds to the
>   HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA readyState.

```
var video = document.querySelector('#videoshow');
video.on('canplay', function() {
   video.play();
   video.style.display = 'block';
});
```

If you are having problems with the dimensions, and since you have jQuery available, you could update the css width/height properties to be exact dimensions:

```
var video = document.querySelector('#videoshow');
$(video).css({
  width: $(window).width() + 'px',
  height: $(window).height() + 'px'
});
video.on('canplay', function() {
   video.play();
   video.style.display = 'block';
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, that helps, but I'm still having the issue of the video not wanting to follow the CSS rule sometimes.  Please check out my edit above

Comment: perfect, that did it!